# How to repeat last block in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code

```
var input = "http://local.app.com/frontend/v12/#/M1WPD/!/abcde/!/fghij/";

var regex = new RegExp("(?:.+?#/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/(?:!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/)*)");

var result = input.match(regex);

console.log(result);

// ["http://local.app.com/frontend/v12/#/M1WPD/!/abcde/!/fghij/", "M1WPD", "fghij"]
```

should print this...

```
["http://local.app.com/frontend/v12/#/M1WPD/!/abcde/!/fghij/", "M1WPD", "abcde", "fghij"]
```

beside...

```
["http://local.app.com/frontend/v12/#/M1WPD/!/abcde/!/fghij/", "M1WPD", "fghij"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why should the result contain 3 capturing groups? You only specified two: `([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})` (appearing twice). A capturing group contains its last matched value. If you want 3 values, have 3 capturing groups.

Comment: But I did say repeat last group {0,} times. Didn't I?

Comment: That doesn't create an additional capturing group

Comment: That's my question, why?

Comment: Because a capturing group is a place which captures tokens. It's like a box. If you only have 2 boxes, no matter how much you try, you can't fit in 3 boxes-worth of items. So what the regexp engine does is go to your last box, empty it, and fill in - that way you can fill 3 loads in 2 boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture `n` number of groups through quantifiers..The result is that it would capture the last occurring match in that particular group!

You have to manually select the groups...

It should be:

```
(?:.+?#/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})/!/([a-zA-Z0-9]{5})
```

---

If there are arbitrary number of matches you can `split` with the below regex

```
/[#!]/|/$
```

The above regex means split the string where there is an occurrence of `/` followed by `#` or `!` followed by `/`

**OR**

`/` followed by end of the string `$`

Comment: I want each and every group. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: You mean I should split groups by #! instead of # and ! both?

Comment: @UmairAshraf use split with `/[#!]/|/$` regex

Comment: It works though. At the end I am getting empty string. Good work!

Comment: @UmairAshraf you can also `match` with `[#!]/(\w+?)/` but i dont know how to iterate matches in javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex("[^0-9a-zA-Z]*\\w{5,}");
```

Make the changes as the above code and try